# Changing Text on a site when there is mouse-over a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

not sure if this is possible but I have text on my site that I would like to change when there is a mouse over on a link.

For instance. The word Home appears half way down a page. When the user puts their mouse over a separate link, I would that word to change to something I specify for that link. Anty way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What have tried? Can you show us the code you have now? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for tips on asking questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<p>hover me!</p>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){
    $("p").html("You are hovering me!");
    },function(){
    $("p").html("hover me!");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your links that want to trigger text changes, then subscribe mouse over event for this class and change the text.. seems like a piece of cake

```
<a href="whatever" class="linkClass" data-text="textToChange">link</a>
```

code

```
$(".linkClass").live("mouseover", OnMouseEnter);

function OnMouseEnter(event){
    var newText = $(event.target).attr('data-text');
    $("#tbxHome").text(newText);
}
```

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I will try to remember avoid XD

Answer (score 0):

If you always know what you want the hover text to be, here's a CSS-only option:

```
<style>
  a:hover .replace-me {
    display:none;
  }
  a:hover:after {
    content:'Switcheroo!';
  }
</style>
<a href="#"><span class='replace-me'>Hover on me!</span></a>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hnvFD